# C++, вопрос про инициализацию объекта типа enum class

Tags: c++, классы, enum, инициализация

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
enum class Variants
{
    FIRST = -1,
    SECOND = 1
};

Variants variant{};
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, что и почему должно оказаться в `variant` после указанной инициализации?

Эксперимент показывает, что в `variant` оказывается 0. Хотя в перечислении нет такого элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случаи членами перечисления являются целочисленные именованные константы FIRST и  SECOND, но экземпляр типа может принимать и другие значения:

```
Variants variant = Variants{ 12 };
variant = Variants(0);
```

В последнем случаи, практически инициализируется значением по умолчанию, поскольку биты интегральных типов по умолчанию инициализируются нулем.

Variants variant{}; это аналогичная инициализация _ инициализировать  variant значением по умолчанию.
Вся разница в том, что кроме Variants{-1} и  Variants{1}, все остальные константы будут неименованными.

Answer (score 4):

У `enum class` underlying type по умолчанию - `int`. Так что в нем можно хранить любое значение `int`а.

Даже если бы это был обычный `enum` без указания underlying type, `0` все равно был бы допустимым значением. В такой enum влезает любое число, которое влезло бы в [битовое поле минимальной длины](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8), достаточной для представления всех элементов этого enum'а (вроде бы, если нет отрицательных элементов, то воображаемое битовое поле беззнаковое).